# Reading a file in JAVA , equals doesn't work

Tags: java, file, equals

I have a txt file and I read it .
This is what it says:

```
CONTRACT
{
    CODE 1
    SERVICE "Pro"
    NAMESURNAME "Takis Papadopoulos"
    PHONENUMBER 6980021739
    DATE "19/3/2007"
    TYPE Internet
    DISCOUNT 10
    MONTHLY_USAGE{
        MB_USED 200
    }
}
```

I created a BufferedReader and I use the line=read.readLine() method. But the problem is that when it comes to this piece of code:

```
if(line.trim().startsWith("SERVICE ")){                                    
    tmp_service = line.trim().substring(8);
    System.out.println(tmp_service);//Prints "Pro"

    if(tmp_service.equals("Pro")){
        System.out.println("1");//Never gets in
    }else if(tmp_service.equals("Internet Family")){
        System.out.println("2")
    }else{
        System.out.println("3");//Prints this
    }
    count++;
    System.out.println(tmp_service);//Prints "Pro"
}
```

It always prints "3", and even though equals should be "true" it isn't. I also tried "startsWith()" but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] rather than just snippets. It's always much easier to help you that way, and the question has more value for future readers.

Comment: What about leading and invisible whitespace? Maybe the `tmp_service` contains `" Pro"`?

Comment: If the format is always the same a regex or some string.split and you can convert all this into object. Even cheking the format and setting default value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you are having quotations in your text so you need to include them in your check

```
 if(tmp_service.equals("\"Pro\"")){
```

A better solution in my opinion would be removing all '"' if you are expecting to have many occurrences, its always better to generalize your cases

Comment: Now it doesn't print anything:(

Comment: sorry its equals not starts with

Comment: it worked, thanks you very much !

Answer (score 1):

You try to compare '"Pro"' to 'Pro'. Don't forget to **escape** the quotes.

**In Java, the escape character is a backslash (\).**

Solution in your case : `if(tmp_service.equals("\"Pro\""))`

[Source Java SE doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html) :
*A character preceded by a backslash (\) is an escape sequence and has special meaning to the compiler. [...] When an escape sequence is encountered in a print statement, the compiler interprets it accordingly. For example, if you want to put quotes within quotes you must use the escape sequence, \", on the interior quotes.*
To print the sentence

```
She said "Hello!" to me.
```

*You would write :*

```
System.out.println("She said \"Hello!\" to me.");
```